# More concise way of regex matching optional portions of a string

Tags: regex, bison, flex-lexer

I'm writing Flex lexer patterns to match a series of commands. Not unlike subversion's command line client, the commands can be shortened to a small but still unambiguous length.

So a command such as:

```
MYCOMMAND
```

Could be entered as either:

```
MYCOMMAND
MCOMMAND
MYCOM
MC
```

The pattern I have been ignorantly writing for these cases looks like:

```
M(Y)?C(O|OM|OMM|OMMA|OMMAN|OMMAND)?
```

And it works fine, but it smells pretty bad especially on very long definitions, is there a shorter way of defining such a match?

Comment: What are the rules for shortening your command? It seems to be arbitrary...

Comment: They are arbitrary per-command, but for the example above, is there a more concise definition?  I'm not looking for a magic general solution. :)

Comment: How would COPYDATA and CONVERTDATA be shortened? How should the regex know where one words ends and the other begins without any casing or other delimiters? How should the regex know, whether the shortest version is unambiguous or not (in the sample, both will have CD as the short command)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use an end-of-token symbol like `$` or `\b` then you could do:

```
MY?C(O|$)(M|$)(M|$)(A|$)(N|$)(D|$)
```

Comment: +1: Cool idea and it is even readable - sort of... One fix though, I think, the "C" should be left alone: `MY?C(O|$)(M|$)(M|$)(A|$)(N|$)(D|$)`

Answer (score 1):

What about `MY?C(O(M(M(A(ND?)?)?)?)?)?` ;-)
IMHO, this is the only other way to write it.

Comment: Hey it reduces duplication, it's an improvement!

Comment: It also reduces readability... You need to decide what is more important for you.

Comment: That's true, the nesting gets a little absurd quickly.